# Prebuilt pages with angular server side rendering

Tags: angular, performance, server-side-rendering

I have been working on an angular application that fetches data from API endpoints built on top of the Django rest framework. I use server-side rendering and do reverse proxy with Nginx to pm2 (running angular rendering server) for each request.

I want to reduce the load time of the application. Currently, the largest contentful page takes 2.8s, and out of which 2.2s are initial server responses (which the app takes to render and complete async requests); I was wondering is there some way to reduce this, can I somehow prebuilt these pages and respond with those, there is no rendering based on users and data change occurs every 4 hours or is there any other ways to reduce initial server response for angular.

Comment: Did you try prerendering? https://angular.io/guide/prerendering

Comment: I considered that, but since the data changes every 4 hours and it is essential and pages are built on data,(including URL), would it be a good option to pretender pages every 4 hours by scheduling or something?